# Adding a progress indicator to Google's new Splashscreen pattern

Tags: android, xml, splash-screen

Having gone through this blog post [Splash Screens the Right Way](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) , i discovered Google's new approach to creating splashscreens.

But my problem with this new method is adding a progress bar/indicator to the splashscreen.

I found several solutions but they are all custom xml layouts instead of Drawables

I also tried creating a progress dialog in my Background_splash.xml which is inside my drawable folder but i got an error that it is not allowed.

My app starts from the splash-screen to App intro activity then to the Main activity.

Is there any way to add a progress indicator/bar to this type of splashscreen?

Below are my codes created using the *Splash Screens the Right Way* Tutorial

**Background_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:drawable="@color/grey"/>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</item>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.domain.app.appintro.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Styles.xml**

```
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is you cannot! If you want to show the splash screen before the app loads, via the theme, it will have to be a static image. 
If you want to show a progress bar AFTER the app loads, for example if you need to download data, then you can add a progress bar to splash activity, which will be shown AFTER the static image and app finished loading. 
If you do not need to wait after app loads, then you are just wasting user time by adding another wait period, and making for a lousy app. 
All of this can be understood from the comments and replies from the article you linked.

Comment: Thanks @lionscribe I read the comments, I found out exactly what you said.. Nevertheless, I figured out you can also tweak this approach to provide rich UX

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to load the progressDialog. You might be trying to download something in the main thread which blocks splash screen to load.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private ProgressDialog pd = null;
private Object data = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Show the ProgressDialog on this thread
        this.pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working..", "Downloading Data...", true, false);

        // Start a new thread that will download all the data
        new DownloadTask().execute("Any parameters my download task needs here");
}

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {
         protected Object doInBackground(String... args) {
         Log.i("MyApp", "Background thread starting");

         // This is where you would do all the work of downloading your data

         return "replace this with your data object";
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
         // Pass the result data back to the main activity
         MyActivity.this.data = result;

         if (MyActivity.this.pd != null) {
             MyActivity.this.pd.dismiss();
         }
     }
}
```

}

Take this as a start point and put this as the inner class of your mainActivity.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! But My splash screen is working plus I forgot to mention that my app shows app intro from the splash screen then to the main activity. How can I incorporate asyncTask with that. All I want to achieve is an indeterminate progress bar in the splash screen BTW, I edited my question. Thanks

Comment: As I understand you, you need to display a progressDialog in the splash Activity? And you are not downloading anything, just a static progressDialog?

Answer (score 0):

As @lionscribe rightly said, there is no way to creating custom splash-screen with this approach. However, This http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-startsmight help those who will like to animate elements in the new splash-screen approach.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.